# Quartz Scheduler and threads

Tags: threadpool, quartz-scheduler

this is kind of a theoretical question. If I have a Quartz scheduler that is configured to use a threadCount of lets say 3 threads. If one of the jobs simply doesn't come to an end because it listens to lets say a stream of some kind (e.g. Twitter), can I assume that there are effectively just 2 threads left for the execution of the pending jobs?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your assumptions are correct. Moreover, if you would have three jobs like this, Quartz would be simply unable to run any other jobs.

However this seems unusual to have a job running forever (and I am not sure if Quartz will play nicely in this case, but most likely this won't be a problem). If you have a piece of code that will occupy the thread all the time, just create that thread manually.